# FileMaker: Is there a way to build an export order in a script?

Tags: filemaker

Question: Is there a way to build an export order while performing a script? I would prefer a FileMaker-native or FileMaker-called AppleScript solution, if one is possible.

Project: The project is a reporting tool which summarizes sales information (units, price, cost) by user-selectable criteria such as: week, quarter, year, location, product, supplier, etc.  I would like a way to specify, at runtime, an export based on the user-selected criteria.

Example: If a user selected units sold summarized by supplier per quarter I would like to be able to have the script select:

Group by:

1. quarter
2. supplier

Export Order

1. quarter
2. units summary by quarter
3. supplier
4. units summary by supplier

There are obviously many permutations, so setting up an export for each individual export for each set of options is infeasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Mikhail's and Chuck's suggestions, I think the best method for this particular project is going to be to build the contents of a .csv in a global field and then Export Field Contents.  The basic outline of what I'm doing:

```
Go to the first record
Loop
  WriteTheRows (see below), comma delimited, to a global field
  Set $thisGroup to the count of records summarized by this summary field
  Exit Loop If Get (CurrentRecord) + $thisGroup >= Get (FoundCount)
  Go to record [Get (CurrentRecord) + $thisGroup]
End Loop
Export Field Contents [global field]
```

**WriteTheRows** is a custom function that does the following:
The output I'm trying to write can be sorted by up to 7 different criteria at the same time (for example: I could summarize supplier sales by quarter or I could summarize quarter sales by supplier)

```
Compare the highest level sort field's value to the last value we found for the highest level sort field.
   If they're different WriteALine to the global field for this sort field, the next sort field, all sort fields down to the lowest level.
   If they're the same, compare the (highest level sort field - 1) to the stored value for the (highest level sort field - 1)
      If they're the same, WriteALine to the global field for the (highest level sort field - 1) on down to the lowest level sort field
      ... repeat until we're down to the lowest sort field
```

**WriteALine** is another custom function which adds the appropriate labels, commas and values using the GetSummary ( revenueSummary ; Evaluate ( "summaryField" & summaryFieldNumber ) as Chuck suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the target format is text-based (i.e. tab- or comma-separated), then I'd export to XML and write a XSLT to summarize it as necessary. To pass parameters to the XSLT I normally export a small XML file to the same folder.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with XML/XSLT exports from FileMaker, but my concern here would be in limiting the data that the end user has access to. Say, for example, that we want to share with a supplier the number of units of their product we sold but not how much revenue we made on their products. If I had a general-purpose XML export, both of those data points would be in the XML file. It seems could hide them by XSLT, but a clever supplier could look at the XML value. Is there a way to further filter the output so that the data isn't just hidden but actually not present?

Comment: Sorry for a late answer. This is not a problem: when exporting to XML, FileMaker doesn't leave the original XML around, only the result of the transformation. There won't be any place to recover the information from.

Answer (score 1):

A solution I can think of is to export calculations rather than the original fields. With the example you give, assume that the user can export up to two fields. You create two calculation fields and two text fields. The text fields store the name of the field to export and the calculation fields use `Evaluate` (or `GetField`) to get the contents of the fields. It gets complicated if you're also exporting date and time fields, but it's still workable. If you need to include the field names in the export, you create an extra record and work your calculations for that record to contain the names of the fields the user has selected.

Not trivial, but still possible.

Comment: This is a great idea.  The problem that I run into is that, since I'm using summary data, I'd have to have a calculation field for each of the possible sort criteria (up to 7) and each of the possible export values (up to 4.)  (All these values are so that I can have, using my example in the first question, a summary value of the units for the entire quarter in addition to a summary value of the units for each supplier during that quarter.)